# SQL How Do I Display All Products for an Order In Separate Columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I'm working with a table in the following format

| Order_ID | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | C |
| 3 | B |

I need to query the data to output like this

| Order_ID | Product_1 | Product_2 | Product_3 | Etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |  |  |
| 2 | B | C |  |  |
| 3 | A | C | B |  |

Basically, I need to show all, or at least several, product_names for a given order_id as separate columns. I found a few answers that suggested using self joins to do this, but that doesn't seem practical when I need to show more than two products.

This is in BigQuery.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: BigQuery--I'll edit the post to reflect that too @tconbeer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This general operation is called pivoting.

Depending on your database and its SQL dialect, there will be different optimal approaches for this. Snowflake and BigQuery, for example, have a PIVOT table operation that does specifically this.

On BigQuery:

```sql
with numbered as (
    select
        *,
        'Product_' || row_number() over (
            partition by OrderID order by ProductName asc
        ) as n
    from my_table
)
select
    *
from numbered pivot(
    max(ProductName) 
    for n in ('Product_1', 'Product_2', 'Product_3')
)
group by Order_ID
```

If your dialect doesn't support this, but does support window functions like `row_number`, then you can manually do something like this to support a pre-defined number of products:

```sql
with numbered as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by OrderID order by ProductName asc) as n
    from my_table
)
select
    OrderID,
    max(case when n = 1 then ProductName end) as Product_1,
    max(case when n = 2 then ProductName end) as Product_2,
    ...
from numbered
group by Order_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

> ..  I need to show all, or **at least several**, product_names for a given order_id as separate columns

Consider below

```
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by Order_ID) index
  from your_table
)
pivot (any_value(Product_Name) Product for index in (1,2,3,4,5))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]